# Unable to update MongoDB collection by matching _id

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, postman

First, I Registered a user using His email and password.

Now if

I try to Update or Make user details by matching the Id assigned by the Mongo Database while registering the user.

it's not accepting it.

error is like this

`Parameter "filter" to find() must be an object, got 60b10821af9b63424cf427e8`

if I parse it like

`Model.find(parseInt(req.params.id))`

it shows a different error.

Well here's the Post Request

```
//Post request to create user details by matching Id.
// Id I am trying to match is the id that was given by the database


app.post("/user/:id", async(req, res) => {
    console.log("not found");

    if (await Model.find(req.params.id)) {
        const users = new Model({
            fName: req.body.fName,
            sName: req.body.sName,
            birth: req.body.birth,
            phone: req.body.phone,
            SSN: req.body.SSN
        });
        const result = await users.save();
        console.log(result);
        return res.send({
            "Success": true,
        });
    } else {
        console.log(req.params.id);
        res.status(404).send({ "message": false });
    }
});
```

Here's the schema

```
const LoginSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    email: { type: String, required: true },
    password: { type: String, required: false },
    otp: String,
    token: String,
    fName: String,
    sName: String,
    birth: Number,
    phone: Number,
    SSN: Number

});
```

Here are the headers I used

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extend: true }));
```

```
Database id assigned which I use

{
  _id: 60b1131271129a3cf8275160,
  email: 'Pak@gmail.com',
  password: '$2b$10$FWAHu4lP9vn14zS/tWPHUuQJlO7mjAUTlPj.FliFAZmCNA23JA3Ky',
  __v: 0
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error:

```
Parameter "filter" to find() must be an object, got 60b10821af9b63424cf427e8
```

means: You need to provide an **object** as the argument of the `find()` method, not a string ("60b10821af9b63424cf427e8" in this case). Moreover, `find()` will give you an array, if you find an item in the database, use `findOne()` instead.

Change from :

```
await Model.find(req.params.id)
```

to :

```
await Model.findOne({_id : req.params.id})
```

Another way is to use `findById()` method like this : `await Model.findById(req.params.id)`

Answer (score 1):

Likely the error is caused by the fact that you're passing a string from the request when Mongoose is expecting an instance of `mongoose.Types.ObjectId`. You should be able to fix the problem by casting the string into said type.

```
await Model.find(mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.params.id))
```